# pagination functions are not working

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I have created a custom made home page where there are name of the categpries. When I click on the categories, I am redirecting to another page named as " page-category.php ", passing the category ID in URl. In page-category.php page I want to capture the id and show the customized post design with photos and excerpt of that particular category. However I want pagination on my page in case number of posts exceed a certain number. None of the pagination function is working properly. here is my code:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
 $npsPosts = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5&cat='.$cat_id.'&paged=' . $paged);
            if($npsPosts -> have_posts()):

        next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
        previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );

          <?php
                while($npsPosts->have_posts()): $npsPosts ->the_post();
                    if ( !in_array( $post->ID, $do_not_duplicate )) {  ?>
                        <div class="horizontal_post_grid_row_col cat-page-box">
                            <div class="horizontal_post_grid_row_col-img">
                                <a href='<?php the_permalink();?>'><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="horizontal_post_grid_row_col_content">
                                <h3 style="margin-bottom:5px;"><a href='<?php the_permalink();?>'><?php the_title();?></a></h3>
                                <span class="author_tag">Reading time : <?php echo reading_time(); ?></span> 
                                <div class="excerpt_content"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                                <div class='keep_reading_text'><a href='<?php the_permalink();?>'>Read more</a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gap-cat">jkn</div>


                    <?php 
              }
                endwhile;

                      next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
          previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
    else:
            endif;
```

I haven't added anything in function.php. What might be the problem?

Comment: What kind of permalinks are you using? If you are not sure, visit WP-Admin > Settings > Permalinks and you will see them there. Also if you can, please post what the URL structure is when you click a pagination link.

Comment: when I click the link I am sending the url as [link](http://example.com?id=108) . I am catching the ID in  "page-category.php " and using the ID I am displaying the posts in grid structure. The url in the category page becomes  "http://example.com/category/?id=108" . However when I use any pagination than the URL changes to  "http://example.com/category/page/2/?id=108" which doesn't show anythng. If this is wrong approach than please correct me.